# Is it possible to draw the following diagram in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, diagram

I wanted to ask if there is any R package that can be used to draw the following diagram?

I have the data in the form of percentages but do not know how to draw such a diagram.

Thank you!

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Asking about packages is off topic in Stack Overflow I'm afraid. It would be possible to make a plot like this from scratch, but it would not be easy. My guess from looking at this one is that it has been created in a graphics program like Illustrator rather than with plotting software as such (neither the areas nor the diameters of the circles are exactly proportional to the numbers, the way the circles overlap appears to be inconsistently applied, and there is a gradient fill on the rings which is a bit gratuitous for plotting software).

Comment: I do not need the exact same result; even just a series of circles arranged linearly that have a diameter proportional the percentage will serve my purpose. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess if you get your data into this format:

```r
df <- data.frame(percents = c(51, 48, 46, 41, 29, 25, 34, 18, 18),
                 label = c("MEDICAL\nSCHOOL\nAPPLICANTS", 
                           "MEDICAL\nSCHOOL\nGRADUATES", 
                           "RESIDENTS", 
                           "FACULTY", 
                           "DIVISION\nCHIEFS", 
                           "FULL\nPROFESSORS", 
                           "SENIOR\nASSOCIATE\nDEANS", 
                           "DEPARTMENT\nCHAIRS", "DEANS"))
df
#>   percents                       label
#> 1       51 MEDICAL\nSCHOOL\nAPPLICANTS
#> 2       48  MEDICAL\nSCHOOL\nGRADUATES
#> 3       46                   RESIDENTS
#> 4       41                     FACULTY
#> 5       29            DIVISION\nCHIEFS
#> 6       25            FULL\nPROFESSORS
#> 7       34    SENIOR\nASSOCIATE\nDEANS
#> 8       18          DEPARTMENT\nCHAIRS
#> 9       18                       DEANS
```

Then you could do something like:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(r = sqrt(percents), x = r + cumsum(lag(2 * r, default = 0))) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = x, r = r, y0 = r), size = 3, color = "#0A0A0A5A") +
  geom_text(aes(x = x, y = r, label = paste0(percents, "%"), size = percents),
            fontface = "bold", color = "#643291") +
  geom_text(aes(x = x, y = 20, label = label), vjust = 0,
            fontface = "bold", color = "gray20", size = 3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, xend = x, y = r + 3, yend = 18),
               color = "#643291", size = 2) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits =c(-5, 25)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(4, 8)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Note that the percentage is proportional to the *area* of the circles, which is a much more honest way to represent data in this type of plot.

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborate response and I apologize for the delayed reply - but I am getting the following error on using the above code - <code>Error in df(.) : argument "df1" is missing, with no default<code>

Comment: @BR27 that's probably because your data frame is not called `df`. Obviously you need to adapt this code to your own data frame. For example, if you use the code in the top block, it will create a data frame called `df`, and you should be able to run the code in the lower block.

Comment: I used the exact same code as you suggested and my data frame is called    df

Comment: Okay, I tried again and this time the circles will not show for some reason, I can only see the percentages and the corresponding labels

Comment: @BR27 Have you installed `ggforce`? - Use `install.packages("ggforce")`

Comment: Yes, I did install ggforce. I replaced "#0A0A0A5A" with "gray" in your code and it works now. Not sure what the problem was but I really appreciate your time and help! Thanks a lot, Allan!

Comment: I have made 2 such diagrams - one with gray and the other with black circles and would like to add a small legend next to these diagrams suggesting that Gray circle = Group A and Black circle = Group B; is there a way to do that? Thank you!